# MySQL INSERT inserting BIT to 1 instead of 0

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, sql-insert

I have the following query which should insert a 0 but instead inserts 1.
It is executed with prepared statements in PHP:

```
$insertsql= 
    "INSERT INTO table1 (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$insertstmt = $pdo->prepare($insertsql);
$insertstmt->execute(array($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, 0));
```

All inserts are performed fine, except a 1 is inserted in column6 instead of a 0.
Column 6 has the datatype BIT.

The query works fine, however, when executing

```
INSERT INTO table1 (column6) VALUE (0);
```

directly in the phpmyadmin 'MySQL' tab.

What am I missing?

EDIT:
Using

```
$insertstmt->execute(array($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, false));
```

works as expected. Why is 0 working directly within a SQL query but not when using pdo to execute it?

Comment: The default binding type when passing the bindings like that is string which means that 0 will become `'0'` and if that's then somehow cast to a boolean it will become 1. I suggest you use [`bindValue`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) with a second parameter to explicitly state what types you're binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly declare this parameter as Boolean when passing it to PDO.

From [the PDO `execute` documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) :

> `input_parameters`
>
> An array of values with as many elements as there are bound parameters in the SQL statement being executed. All values are treated as `PDO::PARAM_STR`.

This is not what you want.

So you would need to change your logic to avoid using the `execute(array())` construct and bind each parameter individually, using `bindValue()`. For boolean :

```
$insertstmt->bindValue(':col6', false, PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
```

Since booleans are just `TINYINT(1)` in MySQL, `PDO::PARAM_INT` should work fine as well :

```
$insertstmt->bindValue(':col6', 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

---

Finally : if this boolean value will always be false, then you may pass it directly to the query, like :

```
$insertstmt->execute(array($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, false));
```

---

As wisely commented by [spencer7593](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107744/spencer7593), another option is to do the type casting from within the SQL. For example one could convert the string to a bit value with :

```
INSERT INTO table1 (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, IF( ? ='0', b'0', b'1') )
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that if the value is actually hard-coded there's no real need to use a parameter for it since parameters are mainly to sanitize input that comes from untrusted sources.

Comment: @apokryfos : parameters also allow RDBM to optimize the query executing by skipping the parsing and preparation of the execution plan. Without bind parameters, the RDBMS usually cannot recognize that you are running the same query again and again.